# Bunch of errors when trying to build app on android studio. How to fix?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, build

So I have a group project I am working on in which we are developing an android app. None of us have ever worked with android before, and have been largely learning off of youtube tutorials. We've been having success, but as I finished with my component, I started getting errors on build and I have no idea what they mean.[Build errors, therest of which just saying the debug failed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIibH.png) it seems like it may just be dependencies or gradle issues, but most of the project is in java and I did this in kotlin so maybe that's an issue, but I am not sure what to do.

Below are the dependencies in my build.gradle(Module:app)

```
dependencies {

    def lifecycle_version = "2.6.1"
    def nav_version = "2.5.3"
    def recyclerview_version = "1.3.0"
    def material_version = "1.4.0-alpha01"

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.5.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:8.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    // ViewModel
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    // Navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    // recyclerview
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$recyclerview_version"

    // material
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$material_version"


    //OTP PIN
}
```

and below here is my entire build.gradle(project)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.31"
    repositories{
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        def nav_version = "2.5.3"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.5.3"
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}
```

I wasn't really sure what to try, but I went and tried to update the versions of implementations like lifecycle, navigation, recyclerview and material. None of these seemed to have worked though. I also tried adding maven to my repositories, but seemingly to no success. I am not sure if this is an error with my actual code, as the project is mostly java but I did my component in kotlin, but I didn't think that should be an issue, and the errors seem to be build/gradle related. Any help/ideas is appreciated.

Comment: `None of us have ever worked with android before` ?? I think you mean: `None of us have ever worked with Android Studio before`. Add that tag. You have problems with Android Studio. Not with Android.

Comment: I disagree. The issue is with the Gradle build, and has nothing to do with the IDE. It would be exactly the same on the command line. Nothing in this question is specific to Android Studio, so it would be an inappropriate tag for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lifecycle-extensions` was discontinued after version 2.2.0, but you are specifying version 2.6.1. You can remove this line:

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
```

You are already using the various `-ktx` versions of the lifecycle libraries, which is now the correct way to get the extensions.

In your `buildscript` block in the other file, you should replace `jcenter()` with `mavenCentral()` and you can remove the following, since it is redundant to using `google()`:

```
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
```

Comment: Interesting, where did you find it? Google's maven repository only lists versions up to 1.1.1.

Comment: I didn’t. I just saw the note in the changelog. See here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.2.0

Comment: It’s there: https://maven.google.com/web/m_index.html#androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0

Comment: @Tenfour4 Ah, OK. OP is using the non androidx variant which has a max version of 1.1.1. The AndroidX version goes to 2.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to import version 2.6.1 of the `android.arch.lifecycle:extensions` library which does not exist.

According to the [Google maven repository](https://maven.google.com/web/m_index.html#android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1) the latest version is 1.1.1.